# SpannableString on button not works for API21?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, spannablestring

I try to put an icon on the toggle button by using SpannableString. and working on API17 but not on API21.

[image: spanable string on button and text]

As you can see, It's work on Button and TextView for API17 but work on TextView only on API21 (The 'Z' is not replace by icon).

```
private SpannableStringBuilder createSpanIcon(int rid, String name){
    Drawable d = getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(rid);
    d.setBounds(0,0,20,20);
    ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(d, DynamicDrawableSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
    SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();

        builder.append("Z\n")
               .append(name)
               .setSpan(imageSpan, 0, 1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        /* This give same result    
        builder.append("Z", imageSpan, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
               .append("RED", new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
               .append("\n" + name);
        */

        return builder;
}
```

and

```
    Button btn = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.myButton);
    SpannableStringBuilder _test = createSpanIcon(R.drawable.tc_g, "Click Me!" );
    btn.setText( _test );

    TextView txt = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.myText);
    SpannableStringBuilder _test2 = createSpanIcon(R.drawable.tc_g, "I'm text" );
    txt.setText( _test2 );
```

Note: I dont want to use `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds`, be cause I'm gonna put the icons on `ToggleButton` so `setTextOn` and `setTextOff` will swap icons for me.

Anyone have an Idea why? and any work around?

Comment: This looks like a bug in `allCaps`. Have you tried turning it off? `txt.setAllCaps(false)`

Comment: Interesting! I didn't notice that the button on API 21 is all caps. 
I will try and let's you know when I'm at my computer.

Comment: @alanv, Yes, it's work. `btn.setAllCaps(false)` solve the problem. Please add your comment as an answer, So I can accept.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can work around this issue by disabling `allCaps` mode, which is `true` by default for Material-styled buttons.

From code,

```
txt.setAllCaps(false);
```

From XML,

```
<Button
    ...
    android:textAllCaps="false" />
```

Comment: I'm working on Android 6.0 and it should be `android:textAllCaps="false"`